# Adding a title to automatically generated unique key ID Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have an issue where I can't seem to figure out how to adjust my code below so I can add a title in conjunction to the numbering. For instance instead of 1, I would want T-1. Anyone have any ideas or quick fixes? The code works when any column asides the unique ID column has info inputted into it.

```
Function Max_Each_Column(Data_Range As Range) As Integer
    Dim TempArray() As Double, i As Long
        If Data_Range Is Nothing Then Exit Function
        With Data_Range
        ReDim TempArray(1 To .Rows.Count)
        For i = 1 To .Column.Count
            TempArray(i) = Application.Max(.Columns(i))
        Next
    End With
        Max_Each_Column = TempArray
End Function
```

This is the code that cause the ID to be created:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Column = 2 Then 'This is the column that causes the ID to be created
'This uses the target offset so it assumes in two spots below that the column to update is "A" and
'that the column is one position to the left of the target column above
    If Target.Offset(0, -1).Value = "" Then
       Target.Offset(0, -1).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Columns("A")) + 1
    End If
End If
```

Comment: Your function doesn't compile. If the return type is `Integer`, `Max_Each_Column = TempArray` is an automatic Type Mismatch. Also `.Column.Count` needs an `s`: `.Columns.Count`.

Comment: @BigBen I tried to change it from Integer to Variant but can't seem to get that to work either. Any ideas?

Comment: The return type of the function has to be the same type as `TempArray`.

Comment: Can you breakdown what that would look like code-wise? @BigBen